# Displaying mouse-hovering on divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make buttons light up when hovering over them with the mouse. however my attempts of doing so do not appear to work at all. I have been using jQuery to make the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#knap").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#knap").fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });
    $('#knap').mouseleave(function() {
        $("#knap").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    });
});
```

here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="party.css"/>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="knap">I don't work!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that nothing happens when I hover over the div. But I have tried doing the exact same thing in codecademy. However there it worked perfectly.

If any of you could help me it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I would strongly suggest the use of css to highlight buttons on hover

Comment: Are you loading jQuery?

Comment: load jquery soucre code

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful here

Comment: Do not complicate what is simple. Use CSS only `:hover`

Comment: @Snappawapa it's trivial for you to create one with the code provided.

Comment: I would also cache #knap in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to solve this in CSS, no need for jQuery for this.

```css
#knap:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(73, 200, 255, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(73, 200, 255, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(73, 200, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="knap">I don't work!</div>
```

Comment: Why the complete change in the action behavior, might I ask?

Comment: It would be nice if the OP explained why this was the accepted answer and what the problem was.

Comment: Especially considering it doesn't do what the OP is trying to do with his code in the question... cc @JakobSchøler

Answer (score 4):

The best approach to achieve this functionality is to use CSS, not jQuery. There is a [built-in pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover) called `:hover` that you an append to your element selector (`#knap`) where you can apply an opacity change.

The `transition` on the original element is to make the opacity change take some time, rather than happen instantly.

```css
#knap {
   transition: 0.5s opacity;
   opacity: 0.5;
}

#knap:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="knap">I don't work!</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. However the OP wants the opposite effect: no opacity on mouse over, but that is pretty easy to fix.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos Oops! Fixed.

Comment: I would also do `transition: 0.5s opacity;`. Otherwise every other property change would take half a second.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos While I try to only provide answers based on the code in the question, that is true; OP might not realize what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try opacity using css for your id element

```css
#knap{
  opacity:.5;
  }
#knap:hover{
  opacity:1;
  }
```

```html
<div id="knap">I don't work!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to load jquery source. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v1ngc5cm/) I leave a JSFiddle that works with the exact code you did.

You can get the same result using only CSS by using the `:hover` selector.